# Client-Server socket setup, how to respond to a determined client

Tags: python, sockets, server

**This question has been edited to focus in a simpler problem**

So I have a basic client-server socket installation, in which the client send a JSON like `{'id': '1', 'value': 'A'}`. At the server side, if I receive a message with `id 2` I want to send a message to the client with `id 1`, telling him that his new `value` is `C`.

This message should be "private", i.e., only `id 1` should receive it, no broadcasting allowed.

How should I approach this problem? How could I keep track of the connections at the server side so that I could send a message to a determined client? The problem is that **it's the server** the one sending the message to the client, not responding to a client's message. I guess it must be with some combination of threading and queues, but still haven't figured out how to do it.

This is the code I have right now at the server, keeping track of the clients using a dict, but it's not working (bad file descriptor at the `sendall('C')` line:

```
track_clients = {}
while True:
    print "waiting for a connection"
    connection, client_address = sock.accept()
    try:
        print "connection from ", client_address
        data = json.loads(connection.recv(1024))
        track_clients[data['id']] = connection

        if data['id'] == '2':
            conn = track_clients['1']
            conn.sendall('C')
        connection.sendall(json.dumps(data))
    finally:
        connection.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code above is OK. The problem is the connection.close() at the finally statement. Removing it, fixes the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at channels http://channels.readthedocs.org/en/latest/. 
Alongside redis (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/redis/)

Comment: I'm not interested in Django. The production server is Tornado, but this is not even what concerns me right now. This question is focused in simple client-server via socket

Comment: ah, I was talking about having a look at how they implemented what you 're asking. Something like https://github.com/andrewgodwin/channels/blob/master/channels/management/commands/runserver.py  maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using [zeromq](http://zeromq.org/) for this task?
It is easy to use and provides high level implementation of common patterns.

From [`zeromq` guide](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all#ZeroMQ-in-a-Hundred-Words)

> ZeroMQ (also known as ØMQ, 0MQ, or zmq) looks like an embeddable
>   networking library but acts like a concurrency framework. It gives you
>   sockets that carry atomic messages across various transports like
>   in-process, inter-process, TCP, and multicast. You can connect sockets
>   N-to-N with patterns like fan-out, pub-sub, task distribution, and
>   request-reply. It's fast enough to be the fabric for clustered
>   products. Its asynchronous I/O model gives you scalable multicore
>   applications, built as asynchronous message-processing tasks. It has a
>   score of language APIs and runs on most operating systems. ZeroMQ is
>   from iMatix and is LGPLv3 open source.

Also it seems like it better to reuse existing libraries because you can focus on your tasks directly while library provides you with all required high-level methods.